# javascript/jquery convert array to string adding something before each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I need to convert the following array into *correction **an object** however I also need to append something before each **object** is printed.

```
var arrayList = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];
```

I need to turn this into the following...

```
{src: 'image1.jpg'},{src: 'image2.jpg'},{src: 'image3.jpg'}
```

I have tried things like:

```
{src: '"+ arrayList.toString+"'}
```

However this just outputs all 3 in one long string. I know that I need to use a loop or jquery `each()` statement however I'm just not sure how to do that and get my final output that I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So are you trying to create an object or a string, it's not really clear ?

Comment: Very sorry I meant to object but said string. I made the corrections to my question.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your fast response... as always love the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an object

```
var arrayList = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];

var obj = arrayList.map(function(item) {
    return {src: item};
});
```

and to turn that into a string

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

or if you just need a string (which makes very little sense as it's not accessible at all ?)

```
var str = '{src : \'' + arrayList.join('\'}, {src : \'') + '\'}';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZC387/3/)

Comment: Don't forget the quotation marks around each `image_.jpg`.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Yeah, that's probably very important, especially the single quotes, so it can't be parsed as JSON or used for anything really ?

Comment: I was just pointing out that the result didn't match the requirement. It's ridiculous to suggest that the data can't be used for anything. Creating custom serialization isn't uncommon.

Comment: @cookiemonster - I can't say that I've ever seen a string like this used for anything? A string that looks like an object but is a string, with single quotes so it's not valid JSON? Just seems too weird, and I was right in this case, but of course it could be used for something or passed to  something that had some sort of strange custom parser instead of using the built in stuff, but I wouldn't say it's very common.

Comment: I just meant that custom serialization is common. Not necessarily this form. Moot point anyway. The guy said "string" more than once when he really wanted an Array of Objects. Details people, details.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Lets agree to agree on that one !

Comment: I'm using this to pass an array of images into magnific popup as follows.... 
    `$('#some-button').magnificPopup({items: [ {src: 'path-to-image-1.jpg'} , { src: 'path-to-image-2.jpg' } ]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to modify each item as desired, then finally `join` to create your entire string.

```
arrayList.map(function (e) {return '{src: \'' + e + '\'}';}).join();
// "{src: 'image1.jpg'},{src: 'image2.jpg'},{src: 'image3.jpg'}"
```

Please notice that though the output looks like *Objects*, this is only making *Strings*.

Comment: @whiteb0x - That's a bold statement as the question is not very clear, but generally a string that looks exactly like an object sounds rather useless, so I'd say the OP doesn't really know what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var arrayList = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];
var Lista = "";
var Top = arrayList.length;
var cont = 1;
$.each(arrayList,function(index, value){
    Lista = Lista + "{src:'"+value+"'}";
    if(cont < Top)
    {
     Lista = Lista + ",";
     cont++;
    }
});
console.log(Lista);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/sV8Fc/